# Division Algebra with every element a root of $K[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

> Let $D$ be a division algebra and $K\subseteq C(D)$ (the center of $D$). If every element of $D$ is a root of a nonzero polynomial in $K[x]$ prove that D is a field.

I believe $D$ will end up being an extension field of $K$ but I am not sure how to procceed.

Comment: Is $D$ finite dimensional over $K$?

Comment: No it is not mentioned, then it would just be $K[d_1,...,d_n]$ so I don't think it is intended anyway

Comment: Wait, doesn’t the statement imply that any finite-dimension division algebra over a field is commutative? (which is false)

Comment: As @Mindlack says, this is not true.  E.g., think about Hamilton's quaternions $\mathbb H$ over $K = \mathbb R$.  Every element of $\mathbb H$ has a minimal polynomial over $\mathbb R$ of degree at most 2.

Comment: Agree with Mindlack and Kimball. The statement is false. Every finite dimensional division algebra has this property. The argument is rather easy. If $z$ is an arbitrary element of $D$, then the set $1,z,z^2,\ldots, z^d$, $d=\dim_{K} D$ is linearly dependent over $K$, hence $z$ satisfies a non-trivial polynomial equation.

Comment: Of course I see it clearly now. Yes the quaternions are a clear counterexample indeed, thank you!